# Can I subclass private members in a derived class?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a base data member class:

```
class DataClass {
}
```

and a subclass:

```
class DerivedDataClass : public DataClass {
}
```

I use DataClass as a private member of a class, DataClassList

```
class DataClassList {
  public:
    // some useful functions here
  private:
    DataClass private_data;
}
```

I want to subclass DataClassList to create a class that can operate on DerivedDataClass

```
class DerivedDataClassList : public DataClassList {
  // how do i get this class to use DerivedDataClass as the private member?
}
```

Can this be done in some form in C++?

EDIT:
Adding some more notes on what I'm trying to do:

`DataClass` has some useful functions that I don't want to redefine in `DerivedDataClass` and `DerivedDataClass` has functions of its own. So, inheritance makes sense. All is good so far.

The next level is the issue. `DataClassList` has useful functions that depend on `DataClass` functions. `DerivedDataClassList` will need to access data/run functions from `DerivedDataClass` *in addition to* the useful functions provided by the base classes.

Without being able to change the private `DataClass` member in `DataClassList` to `DerivedDataClass`, I cannot call functions from `DerivedDataClass` in `DerivedDataClassList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want to use `DataClass` object `private_data` in `DerivedDataClassList`.
If you want to use `DerivedDataClass`, then you need to declare an object of `DerivedDataClass` somewhere (I don't see an object of `DerivedDataClass` anywhere). Or you need to inherit from `DerivedDataClass` - which I again I don't see in your code.

```
class DataClassList 
{
    protected:
        DataClass private_data;
};

class DerivedDataClassList : private DataClassList 
{
    // DataClass object private_data is like a private member here
};
```

If you make `private_data` as a `protected` member of `DataClassList` instead of `private` and you make `DataClassList` a `private base class` of `DerivedDataClassList`, then `private_data` acts like a `private` member of `DerivedDataClassList`.

If your original question was not mistyped and you actually wanted DerivedDataClass object as a private member, then you can use pointers.

```
class DataClassList 
{
    public:
        DataClassList(DataClass * p) : private_data(p) {}
    protected:
        DataClass * private_data;
};

class DerivedDataClassList : private DataClassList 
{
    public:
    DerivedDataClassList():DataClassList(new DerivedDataClass) { }

    // private_data which a pointer to a DerivedDataClass object is like a private member here. 
};
```

Comment: See my answer about "protection of protected".

Comment: @jogojapan Looks like I misread his question. Updated my answer assuming he has mistyped his question.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you don't. Private means private - it belongs to that class alone. The correct way is to have an accessor function.

If there is a particular requirement for this class to access that member, then it should be protected [however, that is a rather silly concept, as it gives no protection at all - anyone who wants to get to that field just needs to derive from the class, and voila, they have free access].

Thanks to jogojapan for pointing out that I'd missed a bit. The answer using templates is one solution. The other is to use a pointer in the baseclass, and then have an accessor function set the `private_data` to the provided class member. Which is "right" depends on what you want to do. For instance, if it's a list of elements of some sort (e.g graphical objects (Window, Menu, etc) or game objects), and you actually want them to be ONE list [or several similar lists], then using pointers is the right solution. If you have several diffferent distinct types of objects that are never used in a common way, then the template class is probably the right way to go.

Comment: Ended up making the object as a protected pointer to the base class.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you use inheritance for this, you'll get the `private_data` member from the base class as a member, albeit an inaccessible one, of the derived class as well. You can't change the data type of a base-class member in a derived class.

I believe using a class template is better in your situation:

```
template <typename Data>
class DataClassList
{
public:
  /*...*/
private:
  Data private_data;
};
```

You need to write the definition above only once, but you can create instances as follows:

```
DataClassList<DataClass>         standard_list;
DataClassList<DerivedDataClass>  derived_list;
```

The former is an object that contains a `DataClass` member, the latter is an object that contains a `DerivedDataClass` member (and no other member).

Comment: Unfortunately, not all the functions in `DerivedDataClassList` have equivalents in `DataClassList` . This prevents me from templating the DataClassList. But, something for me to think about.

Comment: Template specialization may help in this case. But if you can change the member into a pointer or reference, the solution suggested by the other answers may also be a possibility.

Comment: I think the pointer idea would work. Would it require a custom destructor to delete the created objects from their pointers?

Comment: Yes. You would create the objects in the constructor and deallocate them in the destructor. However, if you use smart pointers (e.g. `std::unique_ptr<DataClass>` from C++11, or `boost:scoped_ptr<DataClass>` from Boost), you wouldn't actually have to do anything in the destructor -- it would happen automatically.

Comment: Of course this is only true if these data members are actually created and owned by the `DataClassList`. If there are created outside the class and passed to the `DataClassList` when it is constructed, then responsibility for deallocating them lies with whoever constructed them.

Comment: If you don't want to use pointers, You can (with `DataCallList` defined as above) define `template <typename Data>
class DerivedDataClassList : public DataClassList<Data>{...}`
Then `DerivedDataClassList<DerivedDataClass>` can access the functions in `DerivedDataClass`
But generally you might want to rethink the design. It sounds as if inheritance might not the right mechanism to use here.